# Alias an npm module to a different npm module

Tags: firebase, react-native, webpack, create-react-app, react-native-firebase

I am adding a web interface to my react-native mobile application by first converting it a mono-repo using yarn workspaces to create reusable packages for shared code. I use `react-native-firebase` in the mobile app to capture analytics and to store user profile images. Shared code also captures some analytics. I want to rename the statement

`import Firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app`

to

`import Firebase from 'firebase'`

where `firebase` is the JS NPM module.

Is it possible using a webpack configuration. I am using `create-react-app` to create the web application and have overridden the webpack config using `react-app-rewired` and `customize-cra` and add the following override file

```
const path = require('path')

const { override, babelInclude, addWebpackAlias } = require('customize-cra')

module.exports = override(
  babelInclude([
    /* transpile (converting to es5) code in src/ and shared component library */
    path.resolve('src'),
    path.resolve('../my-shared'),
    path.resolve('../my-config'),
    path.resolve('../my-res')
  ]),
  addWebpackAlias({
    ['@react- native-firebase/app$']: 'firebase'
  })
)
```

But this doesn't work. My main objective is to be able to be able to use Firebase in the shared code used by both the mobile app and web app. I also tried using conditional imports to import `@react-native-firebase/app` in case of mobile and `firebase` in case of web but that didn't work either.

Please share if you know how I can achieve the above goal.